# Put in bold every first word of a text?

Tags: bold

I try to put in bold every first word of a text but i've got an error with every uppercase accented

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\let\mfirstucMakeUppercase\textbf

\begin{document}

\capitalisewords{Lorem ipsum dolor sit}

\capitalisewords{éLorem ipsum dolor sit amet}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It will work as expected if you compile with xelatex or lualatex, instead of pdflatex

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the `mfirstuc` package points out its limitation in handling certain UTF-8 tokens (part 4 of the documentation). It also points out that for accented characters a solution would be to enclose the accented character in curly brackets. So `\capitalisewords{{é}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}` should work without an error in your example.